# PHPUnit - Testing Last Insert ID

Tags: php, phpunit

Can someone pls tell me how do I cover the following exception case in my PhpUnit test?

```
$DB->Insert(db query here...);

$lastInsertID = $DB->InsertID();

if (!$lastInsertID) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to insert new record');
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that your `Insert` should throw Exception instead of silence.

Comment: @sectus, pls elaborate with an example maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you could mock `$DB->Insert` to return `false`

Comment: pls explain with an example? Thanks

Comment: Just went through the doc, but i still think you cannot mock just one of the line in a method and make it return false. `$DB->Insert` in this case

Comment: Mock the $DB instance, the insertID() method.

You should have something like $db = $this->getDB();. In that case mock current object, getDB() method. It should return mocked DbInstance, with mocked insertID() method.

Comment: This is what I have done so far, but hte code coverage does not still covers the `if (!$lastInsertID) {
    throw new Exception('Unable to insert new record');
}` in my main code. Please assist what  should I do to cover those lines?

   `$stub = $this->getMock('DbClass', array('InsertID'));
   $stub->expects($this->once())
     ->method('InsertID')
     ->will($this->returnValue(false));

   $this->assertTrue($stub->InsertID());`

Comment: You are covering wrong class.  
Should be something like  
`  
/* @expectedException */  
function testInsert() {  
$class->setDB($stubbedDB); // InsertID should be mocked to return false  
$class->newRecord(); // code from the Question  
}  
`

It is much better to do what @sectus said.  
`DbClass::InsertID()` should check if query is executed successfully, if not - throw exception. Otherwise you have to check for `InsertID()` in too many places.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the class that does the insert is inheriting a ModelClass which inherits the DbClass that has all the Insert, InsertID methods. So what you suggested is still the correct way of writing the test?